# Optimizing Constants in a Function with a Square Root Term

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting

I am working on a curve fitting problem where I have a series of real data points, and I want to fit a curve to this data. The derivative of the function I am trying to fit has the form:

f'(x) = -sqrt(K1 * x^2 - K2 * x)

Here, (K1) and (K2) are constants that I want to optimize, and (x) is the independent variable which usually dwells around 250. I was using the first value of the independent variable.

However, I am encountering an issue where the expression inside the square root becomes negative during optimization, causing errors. Additionally, the relation between (K1) and (K2) is probably around 250 since the derivative of the data is really low but aside from that scale comparison between the constants and the x is unknown.

I am looking for advice on the following:

1. What strategies can I use to optimize (K1) and (K2) effectively?
2. How can I normalize (K1) and (K2) to improve the optimization process?
3. How can I ensure that the optimizer only explores regions where the expression inside the square root is non-negative?

Any insights or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: An example of data in case where the trouble occurs would be usefull to help you.